# AS3 Exported Class Is not a compile time constant

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I have a piece of art I made on the timeline that I want to turn into a button, so I comverted it to a symbol and exported it to actionscript with a linkage class, but when I compile it and run it I get the error, 1046 type was not found or was not a compile time constant: playButton22

```
        import playButton22;

        var playB22:SimpleButton = new playButton22();
        addChild(playB22);
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
thanks
Scientific

Comment: Same error even if you write `var playB22:playButton22 = new playButton22();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to `import playButton22`.

[image: Screenshot]

See how I have defined the class

and then my code is:

```
var s:Square = new Square();
addChild(s);
```

This works without any issues.

Note: Conventionally, you should use CamelCase for your class definitions, so your class name should be `PlayButton22`. And, use headlessCamelCase for your variables (so `playB22` is fine)